# Dynamic java business rule validation

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am struggling to fit below use case.

Requiremnet:Dyamic comparison tool.Input to method is a json and then map it java class and then run some validation and persist it to database along with the result of the validation.
This looks simple when your json is predefined.You can create a java class and write code to do the required validation.
My use case is to be  able  to handle any kind of json and then create a beam dynamically and run some rule on it on the go

Now for example

Json 1:Student info json which has information about name,class,marks.

Validation:Persist data to DB only if marks>50

Json 2:Order info json which has information about order id,price,order type.

Validation:Persist data to DB only if order type= shoe.

Things i need to do:

Step 1: create a test file that has info regarding data type of validation object and the validation condition.
(Only way i think i can pass validation rule dynamically.Like how Apache does it on log stash.
Eg: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/configuration-file-structure.html)

Step 2:Pass this test file while compiling your spring boot project.

```
Sample text file format

input{
name:String
class:String
grade:String
}
ValidationRule{
marks>50
}
output{
//if in case you don't want to persist all the data to db.You can mention which        
field to use.
}
```

Now with the help of this text file i am assuming that java can create a bean.Then  apply business rule to it.

Comment: I only skimmed this but it sounds like you want to use Drools or something similar.

Comment: If Drools is too heavy, one more option - [groovy  + Hibernate validation](https://github.com/kellyrob99/groovy-hibernate-validator)